# Windows 7 suddenly high CPU increase

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu

I'm having problem with my Windows 7 and it is driving me crazy. In the past few days I get suddenly CPU increase. When I checked CPU usage by processes it looks like every open chrome tab has 5-15 %, ProcessExplorer 15%, NodeJS 10%, Sublime 10%, etc, etc. Like every process of last recently used program has increased CPU. This CPU increase last for about 20 seconds - then everything is back to normal. And it repeats randomly - sometimes every x minutes, sometimes once in 2 hours.

First I thought it was youtube videos. So I closed all youtube tabs but CPU increase event repeated anyways.

Second I thought is was Flash - but no.

Third - I was checking services and then I switched Windows Search so off. It looked like solution, but then, after a few hours - everything repeated again.

I cannot figure it why is this happening. I don't want to format my laptop - too much time to set everythnig back again. I checked computer with Microsoft Essentials, I cleaned it with CCleaner - nothing.

So If anyone can give me any suggestion - I would be very happy.

Thanks for any idea about it and Best Regards to you all

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: I didn't tried that. I solved my problem - see my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random CPU increases like this is often the result of spyware or viruses. You already used Microsoft Security Essentials to scan for viruses. I would suggest to do the same for spyware. Hitman Pro and Malware bytes are my 2 choices to test if you have these.

If you have a bad infection, I would strongly suggest to format your hard drive and reinstall windows, because you cannot be sure you remove everything. If hitman pro finds more than 3 different serious treats (they're red) consider reformat over cleaning.

Comment: It turned out that I had a few spyware on my OS. I used Hitman and everything is ok now.